# "Approach mathematics like/as a creative activity"

Tags: word-choice

Given the sentence:

> Teachers in this country have generally been trained either to approach mathematics **like/as** a creative activity or that they should force students to memorize rules and principles without truly understanding how to apply them.

Should I use *like* or *as*?

Comment: Approach or force? Seems like an odd either or pair to me. What about the case where teachers force a creative approach to mathematics? Do you mean to imply that some teachers encourage students to take a creative approach to mathematics, while others teach students to approach math prescriptively?

Answer (score 3):

At least to me, they mean two quite different things. I'm not sure if that is owing to grammar, semantics, pragmatics or just my individual perception, though.

> approach mathematics ***like*** a creative activity

--> approach mathematics ***like you would approach*** a creative activity

> approach mathematics ***as*** a creative activity

--> approach mathematics ***as if it (mathematics) were*** a creative activity

Some may still argue that the two interpretations are also essentially the same.

Comment: You can get to the same place by numerous routes, depending on the context. Though it's not necessary to presuppose a deleted counterfactual _were_ with _as if_; it might be, after all, just one of a number of hypotheses, rather than something not hypothesized at all.

Comment: Kris, I hadn;'t seen your answer until I posted mine, but I think we agree and you've phrased it more concisely.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely say "as".
I find it difficult to analyse/explain exactly why, but:
I think "as" implies that mathematics **is** (or can be a creative activity), and hence 
mathematics is within the group of creative activities.
On the other hand, mathematics is not "like" a creative activity: it either is one or it isn't one. With "like" you are comparing mathematics with another (parallel) activity, not with a group which contains it.

With "like", you are effectively saying "Teachers ... approach mathematics like [they approach] creative activities."
With "as", you are effectively saying "... approach mathematics as [if it were] a creative activity.

I think I would use "like" where there are two parallel, but separate, activities being compared, but "as" where one activity is being compared with a group within which it fits.

Comment: Good thing we posted almost at the same time. And great we think alike. I'd say the answers complement each other to form a reasonably sound explanation.